# Why does MYSQL DB return a corrupted value when averaging over a Django models.DateTimeField?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, mariadb

I'm running a Django application on top of a MySQL (actually MariaDB) database.

My Django Model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Avg, Max, Min, Count

class myModel(models.Model):
    my_string = models.CharField(max_length=32,)
    my_date = models.DateTimeField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_stats():            
        logger.info(myModel.objects.values('my_string').annotate(
                count=Count("my_string"), 
                min=Min('my_date'), 
                max=Max('my_date'), 
                avg=Avg('my_date'),
            )
        )
```

When I run `get_stats()`, I get the following log line:

```
[2015-06-21 09:45:40] INFO [all_logs:96] [{'my_string': u'A', 'count': 2, 'avg': 20080507582679.5, 'min': datetime.datetime(2007, 8, 2, 11, 33, 53, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'max': datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 13, 5, 20, 6, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]
```

The problem I have with this is that the average of the my_date field returned by the database is: `20080507582679.5`. Look carefully at that number. It is an invalid date format.

Why doesn't the database return a valid value for the average of these two dates? How do I get the actual average of this field if the way described fails? Is Django DateTimeField not setup to do handle averaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1: Why doesn't the database return a valid value for the average of these two dates?**

**A:** The value returned is expected, it's well defined MySQL behavior.

> MySQL automatically converts a date or time value to a **number** if the value is used in a **numeric context** and vice versa.

MySQL Reference Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

---

In MySQL, the **`AVG`** aggregate function operates on *numeric* values.

In MySQL, a **`DATE`** or **`DATETIME`** expression can be evaluated in a *numeric* context.

As a simple demonstration, performing an *numeric* addition operation on a `DATETIME` implicitly converts the datetime value into a number. This query:

```
  SELECT NOW(), NOW()+0
```

returns a result like:

```
  NOW()                                NOW()+0  
  -------------------  -----------------------
  2015-06-23 17:57:48    20150623175748.000000
```

Note that the value returned for the expression **`NOW()+0`** is *not* a `DATETIME`, it's a *number*.

When you specify a `SUM()` or `AVG()` function on a `DATETIME` expression, that's equivalent to converting the `DATETIME` into a number, and then summing 
or averaging the number.

That is, the return from this expression `AVG(mydatetimecol)` is equivalent to the return from this expression: `AVG(mydatetimecol+0)`

What is being "averaged" is a numeric value. And you have observed, the value returned is not a valid datetime; and even in cases where it happens to look like a valid datetime, it's likely not a value you would consider a true "average".

---

**Q2:  How do I get the actual average of this field if the way described fails?**

**A2:** One way to do that is to convert the datetime into a numeric value that can be "accurately" averaged, and then convert that back into a datetime.

For example, you could convert the datetime into a numeric value representing a *number of seconds* from some fixed point in time, e.g.

```
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2015-01-01',t.my_date)
```

You could then "average" those values, to get an average *number of seconds* from a fixed point in time. (NOTE: beware of adding up an extremely large number of rows, with extremely large values, and exceeding the limit (maximum numeric value), numeric overflow issues.)

```
  AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2015-01-01',t.my_date))
```

To convert that back to a datetime, add that value as a *number of seconds* back to a the fixed point in time:

```
  '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2015-01-01',t.my_date)) SECOND
```

(Note that the `DATEIME` values are evaluated in the timezone of the MySQL session; so there are edge cases where the setting of the `time_zone` variable in the MySQL session will have some influence on the value returned.)

MySQL also provides a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function which returns a unix-style integer value, number of seconds from the beginning of the era (midnight Jan. 1, 1970 UTC). You can use that to accomplish the same operation more concisely:

```
  FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.my_date)))
```

Note that this final expression is really doing the same thing... converting the datetime value into a number of seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC, taking a numeric average of that, and then adding that average number of seconds back to '1970-01-01' UTC, and finally converting that back to a `DATETIME` value, represented in the current session `time_zone`.

---

**Q3: Is Django DateTimeField not setup to do handle averaging?**

**A:** Apparently, the authors of Django are satisfied with the value returned from the database for a SQL expression **`AVG(datetime)`**.

Comment: Thanks. That's too bad. It seems like a bug.

Comment: @SaqibAli: It probably *would* be considered a bug in MySQL if it wasn't documented behavior. But because the behavior is described and documented in the Reference Manual, it's not considered a bug. (Other databases will throw an error if you attempt to do `AVG(datetime)`, and Django will return that error.)

Comment: How can I write the Django to get the sum of UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.my_date) in the following expression? `myModel.objects.values('my_string').annotate(count=Count("my_string"), min=Min('my_date'), max=Max('my_date'), sum=Sum(WHAT_ GOES_HERE),)` Once I get that, I can figure out the average pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  Use a TIMESTAMP field instead of a DATETIME field

Plan B:  Convert DATETIME to TIMESTAMP during the computation:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`my_date`))))
```

(Sorry, I don't know the Django syntax needed.)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `values()`, Django will not convert the value it got from the database-python connector. It's up to the connector to determine how the value is returned.

In this case, it seems that the MySQL connector returns a string-representation with the separators removed. You can try to use `datetime.strptime()` with a matching `format` to parse it into a `datetime` object.

Comment: Except it's not a timestamp - it's eight orders of magnitude too big. Actually it appears to be a date string with all the separators removed.

Comment: .....And some leading/padding zeroes removed so you can't tell where all of those boundaries were.