# How to use Django ORM to function on a field

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, orm

This question is a follow-up to [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963319/why-does-mysql-db-return-a-corrupted-value-when-averaging-over-a-django-models-d).

I'm running a Django application on top of a MySQL (actually MariaDB) database.

My Django Model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Count, Sum

class myModel(models.Model):
    my_string = models.CharField(max_length=32,)
    my_date = models.DateTimeField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_stats():            
        logger.info(myModel.objects.values('my_string').annotate(
                count=Count("my_string"), 
                sum1=Sum('my_date'),
                sum2=Sum(# WHAT GOES HERE?? #),
            )
        )
```

When I call `get_stats`, it gives me the count and the sum1.
However, for `sum2`, I want the sum of the following Database expression for each matching row: `my_date + 0` (this converts it to a true integer value).

What should I put in the expression above to get that sum returned in `sum2`?

When I change it to `sum2=Sum(F('my_date'))`, I get the following exception: http://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/50bf572a972bae5d2871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but try `F() expression`

```
from datetime import timedelta

myModel.objects.annotate(
    count=Count("my_string"), 
    sum1=Sum('my_date'),
    sum2=Sum(F('my_date') + timedelta(days=1))
).values('my_string', 'count', 'sum1', 'sum2')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions

Comment: When I do sum2=Sum(F('my_date')), I get the following exception: gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/50bf572a972bae5d2871. I don't even get the chance to add +0.

Comment: hm I've tested on my django 1.8 project Product.objects.values('id').annotate(sum1=Sum(F('price') + 50)) and it works ... added date_created with default=datetime.datetime.now an it works too

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030 this ticket was closed 7 months ago ...

Comment: Ah, Ok. I was using Django 1.7.1. I'm now upgrading to 1.8.2 and will report back.