# How to write Django QuerySet to get UNIX_TIMESTAMP of a DateTimeField?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

This question is a follow-up to the one [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963319/why-does-mysql-db-return-a-corrupted-value-when-averaging-over-a-django-models-d).

Suppose I have the following Django model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum

class myModel(models.Model):
    my_string = models.CharField(max_length=32,)
    my_date = models.DateTimeField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_stats():            
        logger.info(myModel.objects.values('my_string').annotate(
                count=Count('my_string'), 
                sum=Sum(F('my_date')+0)), #THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE. TO WHAT??
            )
        )
```

Instead of calculating the Sum of `my_date`, I would like to calculate the sum of the MySQL expression `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('my_date')`. How can I modify the Django QuerySet above to accomplish that?

*Note: this question not a duplicate of [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime) because I am asking how to get this value from a QuerySet (IE: How do I get the Database to return this value). In that question, there is no Database. It is straight non-Django python. I'm using Django.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [func-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import Func, F, Sum

queryset.annotate(sum=Sum(Func(F('my_date'), function='UNIX_TIMESTAMP')))
```

Comment: I know this question was tagged MySQL, but for anyone else looking for a Postgres solution to the same problem, there is a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47446398)