# function UNIX_TIMESTAMP does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to convert my datetime to unix timestamp. I've tried doing several ways and the error is all the same. I am not very sure what I am suppose to do.

`date_joined` is like this `2017-09-30 10:24:44.954981+00:00`

```
function unix_timestamp(timestamp with time zone) does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


User.objects.annotate(photo_time=Func(F('date_joined'),function='UNIX_TIMESTAMP'))
User.objects.extra(select={'photo_time':"to_unixtime(date_joined)"})
#also tried and UNIX_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because Postgres won't let you do that ([see here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2796/how-do-i-get-the-current-unix-timestamp-from-postgresql)). If you really don't need the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, you need [`Extract`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/)

```
User.objects.annotate(photo_time=Extract('date_joined', 'epoch').get())
```

Of course, you could also define a `TO_UNIXTIME` stored procedure/function, but that seems a bit over the top.